# 22.04 put a desktop launcher in the favorites launcher bar?

Tags: unity, launcher, .desktop

I've created a .desktop launcher to run a .sh script file that launches a program.

The desktop shortcut works, but I don't want to have to go to the desktop every time to run it. I want to put it in the launcher / favorites / dock bar.

How do I install this - or some - shortcut to the program to the launcher bar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to to put your shortcut into the /home/USERNAME/.local/share/applications folder.
Then it will appear in the app menu from where you'll be able to lock it to the launcher.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. The first half of what you posted was the answer!

(The "drag the shortcut" part doesn't work.)